# ModelSim Install in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: intel, modelsim, ubuntu-22.04

I am using **Ubuntu 22.04 LTS** as my OS system. I need to install **modelSim** for participating **Verilog** or **HDL** . But I am failed to do it. How to **Install ModelSim in Ubuntu 22.04** ? Is there any terminal command?

I downloaded modelSim Version from [***"Intel Web Site"***](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/software-kit/750368/modelsim-intel-fpgas-standard-edition-software-version-18-1.html) . It is a .run file. And I failed to install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since modelSim requires 32bit libraries we use the following commands to install the requirements.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Then update your system:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install the requirements for modelSim

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32ncurses6 libxft2 libxft2:i386 libxext6 libxext6:i386
```

After that, Download the ModelSim - Intel FPGA edition installer (both packages) from the Intel homepage.

Make the installer executable

```
chmod +x ModelSimSetup-20.1.1.720-linux.run
```

Run the installer and install ModelSim:

```
./ModelSimSetup-20.1.1.720-linux.run
```

I hope this helps